# $\cos{x}\cdot\cos{2x}>0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Problem is to solve this inequality
>   $$\cos{x}\cdot\cos{2x}>0$$

**My approach:**
Rewrite product as sum of $\cos$.
$$\frac{1}{2}[\cos({-x})+\cos{(3x)}]>0$$
$$\cos({x})+\cos{(3x)}>0$$
But I don't have idea how to continue.

Comment: Better not continue. Just consider when is a product of two things (in this case $\cos x$ and $\cos(2x)$ greater than zero.

Comment: It's not true when $x=\dfrac \pi3$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I suppose this is the question, i.e., for which $x$ is it true.

Answer (score 3):

Since\begin{align}\cos(x)\cos(2x)&=\cos(x)\bigl(2\cos^2(x)-1)\\&=2\cos^3(x)-\cos(x).\end{align}you can consider here the map $f(x)=2x^3-x$, with $x\in[-1,1]$. It is easy to see that $f(x)>0$ if and only if $x\in\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)\cup\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right]$. So, see when is it that $\cos x\in\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)\cup\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right]$

Comment: I am a little confused. Perhaps I am missing a key point. For the source of my confusion, see [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l9jwqm9jql). Sure $\cos (x) > 0$ when $\cos x\in\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)\cup\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right]$. But this surely does not give all $x$ for which $\cos(x)\cos(2x)>0$. Can you elaborate a little more? Thanks!

Comment: Please, read what you wrote in the last comment. You wrote (among other things) that $\cos(x)>0$ when $x\in\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)$. Clearly, every number of the interval $\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)$ is smaller than $0$. So, you are saying that when $\cos(x)$ belongs to this interval of negative numbers, then $\cos(x)$ is actually greater than $0$. Did you really mean to say that?

Comment: Ah no. I foolishly miswrote what I was trying to say. Let me try to reword my comment.

Comment: I figured out why I was confused. Let $g(x) = 2\cos^3(x) - \cos(x)$. $g(x) > 0$ when $\cos x\in\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)\cup\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right]\implies x\in\left(-\frac{3\pi}4, -\frac{\pi}2\right)\cup\left(-\frac{\pi}4, 0\right]$. This is where my mistake lies. In fact, $\cos x\in\left(-\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)\cup\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},1\right]$ when $x\in\left(-\frac{3\pi}4, -\frac{\pi}2\right)\cup\left(-\frac{\pi}4, \frac{\pi}4\right)\cup\left(\frac{\pi}2,\frac{3\pi}4\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting the product as a sum is not a good idea here. Just determine the sign of each factor, i.e. $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2x)$, and then consider the product of the signs.

In the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, $\cos(x)>0$ for $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and 
$\cos(2x)>0$ for $x\in [-\pi,-3\pi/4)\cup (-\pi/4,\pi/4)\cup (3\pi/4,\pi]$.

Can you take it from here?